# Why can't I centre adjust my title in ggplot?

Tags: r

I'm using ggplot to make stacked bar graphs in R. Everything is working well, and I have the title assigned to the plot, but nothing I try will get it to centre. My code at the moment is (with some labels changed):

```
pddis$row <- seq_len(nrow(pddis))
pddis2 <- melt(pddis, id.vars = "row")

ggplot(pddis2, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=row)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="fill") +
xlab("\nDis") +
ylab("Percentage\n")+
ggtitle("Distribution of PD responses)+
guides(fill=guide_legend(title="PD"))+
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
scale_fill_continuous(labels = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4"))+
theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))+
theme_classic()
```

I have also changed `ggtitle` to `opts` and `labs(title=)`, and used `adj=0.5` in various ways, but none of these work either. Apologies if this is obvious, but I just can't work out what I'm doing wrong. The code still runs and produces the plot with these other arguments (but not `opts`, but the title just isn't centre aligned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`theme_classic` is overriding your code. try adding

```
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

After the `theme_classic` command. For example,

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(wt,mpg)) + geom_point() + 
labs(title = 'xyz') + 
theme_classic() +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! I thought it might have had something to do with having two themes, so I started putting the arguments within the `theme_classic()` function, but that just produced errors. I also tried moving `theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))` to immediately after `ggtitle()`, but that didn't do anything so I stopped moving it around. Suppose I should have moved it around some more. Thanks again.